# nginx & uwsgi not redirecting to subpath, getting 404

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I have an nginx setup to redirect any calls to the URL to a django application served via uwsgi. For some reason everything works fine for the root of the page, but as soon as I try to access any subpath I get a 404 error message.

**Example:**

```
https://my-domain.de/
```

Works fine, I get the index page I want to see.

```
https://my-domain.de/dashboard/
```

Does not work, I only get a 404 error from nginx.

I tried about every possible solution I was able to find via Google for about 3h now and I have absolutely no idea why this does not work. Can anyone tell me what my config is missing that causes this behavior?

**System information:**

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04
- nginx/1.10.1
- Python 2.7.6

The django application is served with the following command:

```
uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:8000 -b 32768 --file path/to/app/wsgi.py
```

The nginx server configuration looks like this:

```
upstream myapp {
    server localhost:8000;
}

# Enforce HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my-domain.de;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/my-domain.de.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/my-domain.de.key;

    root /var/www;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name my-domain.de;
    underscores_in_headers on;

    location = / {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass myapp;

            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location ^~ /static/ {
            alias /full/path/to/app/static/;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `location = /` only matches `/`, you probably need `location /`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my problem. If you would post it as an answer I will happily accept it.